# Get data from document DB using multithreading/parallel

Tags: c#, multithreading, list, parallel.foreach

I have the JSON documents in the document DB (~30k documents) where each document has a unique ID something like AA123, AA124. There is a tool we use to pull those documents from the document DB where it has a restriction of 500 documents per GET request call. So this has to go through 60 times GET requests to fetch the result which takes sometime. I am looking to get this optimized to run this in quick time(run threads parallely), so that I can get the data quickly. Below is the sample code on how I am pulling the data from the DB as of now.

```
private int maxItemsPerCall = 500;

public override async Task<IEnumerable<docClass>> Getdocuments()
{
    string accessToken = "token";
    SearchResponse<docClass> docs = await db.SearchDocuments<docClass>(initialload, accessToken); //Gets top 500

    List<docClass> routeRules = new List<docClass>();
    routeRules.AddRange(docs.Documents);

    var remainingCalls = (docs.TotalDocuments / maxItemsPerCall);

    while (remainingCalls > 0 && docs.TotalDocuments > maxItemsPerSearch)
    {
        docs = await db.SearchDocuments<docClass>(GetFollowUp(docs.Documents.LastOrDefault().Id.Id), requestOptions);
        routeRules.AddRange(docs.Documents);
        remainingCalls--;
    }
    return routeRules;
}    

private static SearchRequest initialload = new SearchRequest()
{
    Filter = new SearchFilterGroup(
                new[]
                {
                    new SearchFilter(Field.Type, FilterOperation.Equal, "documentRule")
                },
                GroupOperator.And),
    OrderBy = Field.Id,
    Top = maxItemsPerCall,
    Descending = false
};

private static SearchRequest GetFollowUp(string lastId)
{
    SearchRequest followUpRequest = new SearchRequest()
    {
        Filter = new SearchFilterGroup(
                new[] {
                    new SearchFilter(Field.Type, FilterOperation.Equal, "documentRule"),
                    new SearchFilter(Field.Id, FilterOperation.GreaterThan, lastId)
                },
                GroupOperator.And),
        OrderBy = Field.Id,
        Top = maxItemsPerCall,
    };
    return followUpRequest;
}
```

Help needed: Since I am using the each GET request(500 documents based on IDs depending on the ID of the previous run), how can I use to run this parallely (atleast 5 parallel threads at a time) fetching 500 records per thread (i.e. 2500 parallely in total for 5 threads at a time). I am not familiar with threading, so it would be helpful if someone can suggest how to do this.

Comment: This seems like a I/O workload (making requests to a database), so I don't think that multithreading will help too much. Are you sure that you can extract more documents per second from your database by bombarding it with multiple concurrent requests?

Comment: Please share source code containing Get Request

Comment: @TheodorZoulias: Sorry, I havent checked that and this was the effort to start testing to see if I am able to do it or not. I will also check this with the document DB team and see if we can do concurrent request.

Comment: @SAM: We have been provided with an API and nuget package by the DB team. So we use their methods to get the data by initializing their methods. I am not exactly sure if adding that would help here. I am just trying to understand how can I retrieve the data in 2 or more threads when calling an API which has a limitation of 500 documents retrieval per GET request. As of now I do 1 by 1 call and retrieve the data, order them by document ID value and capture the last ID value of the previous batch and based on that I pick the next batch. Hope this information helps.

Comment: A quick and dirty experiment about the capabilities of the database at serving more than one concurrent requests for 500 documents each, would be to run concurrently two processes (run the same app twice), and measure the time it takes for both processes to finish. The good scenario is that the time would be more or less the same with running only a single process. The bad scenario is that the time would be doubled or more.

Comment: @Dhillli4u i would suggest you to call API methods by using multi-threading (5 threads simultaneously) so that 2,500 documents can be retrieved asynchronously, but there is a challenge in your case that you have to use last ID value before picking next batch. You can avoid it if your DB team returns document already ordered/sorted by document ID.

Comment: @SAM That is unfortunately my problem now :(

Comment: @TheodorZoulias: I am exactly now sure on how to do that in parallel. Currently I have it in single threaded only.

Comment: @Dhillli4u: How can you make concurrent requests if you don't know what id to pass into `GetFollowUp`?

Comment: @StephenCleary I am trying to get that sorted. Will let you know if I have any progress.